AVX rounding from the instruction
I noticed that with AVX the rounding mode can be taken from the MXCSR register and this default can be suppressed by the instruction (EVEX.RC), allowing the instruction to specify a rounding mode which is used only for this operation. This may be easy for an assembler programmer, but is there a way to specify the rounding mode with the intrinsics like _mm256_add_pd or _mm256_mul_pd ?

Including the rounding mode in the instruction is an AVX-512 feature, and beyond that, also only works with the 512-bit version of the instruction. The bits that encode the rounding mode are also reused to encode the register size (which meaning those bits have depends on the EVEX.b bit and on what kind of instruction it is), so with the encoding of the EVEX prefix being what it is, it really is impossible to have rounding control on an instruction that operates on 256-bit registers.
Applicable AVX-512 intrinsics such as _mm512_add_round_pd and _mm512_mul_round_pd (and their masked variants - masks can be combined with rounding control) take a rounding specifier as their last argument.

AVX10.2 will allow embedded rounding overrides in 256-bit vectors.  Some future Intel desktop / laptop CPUs will have that.  (But not full AVX-512 or AVX10-512, so they can still have E-cores which don't handle 512-bit instructions.)  https://cdrdv2-public.intel.com/784343/356368-intel-avx10-tech-paper.pdf  . So there will at some point be _mm256_add_round_pd, but it still won't work with AVX1 or AVX2, only AVX10.2.  (AVX10.1 coming in Granite Rapids is basically just AVX-512FP16 and earlier with the 512-bit support made optional, without the new embedded-rounding for 256-bit vectors.)
